# Pig Simple Dump function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My Input file is below . I am trying to dump the loaded data in relation. I am using pig 0.12.

```
a,t1,1000,100
a,t1,2000,200
b,t2,1000,200
b,t2,5000,100
```

I entered into HDFS mode by entering pig

```
myinput = LOAD 'file' AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,amt:int,rate:int);
```

if i do dump myinput then it shows the below error.

describe, illustrate works fine..

so

```
dump myinput ;
```

As soon i enter the dump command i get the below error message.

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC - FailoverProxy: Failing this Call: submitJob for error   (RemoteException): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:  org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User 'myid' cannot perform operation SUBMIT_JOB on queue default.
Please run "hadoop queue -showacls" command to find the queues you have access to .
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ACLsManager.checkAccess(ACLsManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:4541)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:993)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1322)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1320)



ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias myinput
```

Is this access issues? kind of privilege issue? 
Can someone help me

Comment: can you describe your setup? it seems to be some issue related to hadoop queue.

Comment: MY_QUEUE =demo  I just tried with Pig -DMapred.local.job.queue.name=demo ..then it worked... yes ..it sa queue issue..

Comment: Try
% hadoop queue -showacls
It should show which queues you're allowed to submit.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mention any `load functions like PigStorage('\t')` then it reads data with the column separator as tab(\t) by default.

In your data, the column separator is comma(,)

So Try this one,

```
myinput = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,amt:int,rate:int);
```

Hope it should work..

Answer (score 0):

you could describe your input data(separator), in your case comma : 
try this code please :

```
myinput = LOAD 'file'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:chararray,a2:chararray,amt:int,rate:int);
```